# Check in PHP if subranges cover a parent range date

Tags: php, date

I need to check using PHP if a range is covered by sub-ranges dynamically added.

For example for range: `2019-06-07 10:00:00 - 2019-06-09 11:00:00`

with subranges:

```
2019-06-07 10:00:00 - 2019-06-07 23:59:59
2019-06-08 00:00:00 - 2019-06-09 11:00:00
```

IS OK

but with subranges:

```
2019-06-07 10:00:00 - 2019-06-07 23:59:59
2019-06-08 00:00:00 - 2019-06-09 10:00:00
2019-06-09 10:30:00 - 2019-06-09 11:00:00
```

IS NOT OK because there is a gap: `2019-06-09 10:00:00 to 2019-06-09 10:30:00`

My goal is only return true or false.

I'm not sure how to start approaching this check without pain.

Comment: What are these ranges? DatePeriods? Arrays of DateTime objects?

Comment: Why don't you just loop over them and check if the end point of each element matches the start point of the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over them and check the time difference between the start element of one range against the end element of the previous range.

```
$TimeRange = array();
$TimeRange[0]['start'] = '2019-06-07 10:00:00';
$TimeRange[0]['end'] = '2019-06-07 23:59:59';
$TimeRange[1]['start'] = '2019-06-08 00:00:00';
$TimeRange[1]['end'] = '2019-06-09 11:00:00';

for($i = 0; $i <= count($TimeRange) - 1; $i++)
{
    if(isset($TimeRange[($i + 1)]))
    {
        $StartTime = strtotime($TimeRange[($i + 1)]['start']);
        $EndTime = strtotime($TimeRange[$i]['end']);
        $SecondsDiff = $StartTime - $EndTime;
        echo $i . ": " . $StartTime . " vs " . $EndTime . " = " . $SecondsDiff . "<br>\n";
        if($SecondsDiff > 1)
            return false;
    }
}
echo "<hr>Broken check<br>";
$TimeRange = array();
$TimeRange[0]['start'] = '2019-06-07 10:00:00';
$TimeRange[0]['end'] = '2019-06-07 23:59:59';
$TimeRange[1]['start'] = '2019-06-08 00:00:00';
$TimeRange[1]['end'] = '2019-06-09 10:00:00';
$TimeRange[2]['start'] = '2019-06-09 10:30:00';
$TimeRange[2]['end'] = '2019-06-09 11:00:00';

for($i = 0; $i < count($TimeRange); $i++)
{
    if(isset($TimeRange[($i + 1)]))
    {
        $StartTime = strtotime($TimeRange[($i + 1)]['start']);
        $EndTime = strtotime($TimeRange[$i]['end']);
        $SecondsDiff = $StartTime - $EndTime;
        echo $i . ": " . $StartTime . " vs " . $EndTime . " = " . $SecondsDiff . "<br>\n";
        if($SecondsDiff > 1)
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It work nice! I've improved your code: 1. sort array $timeRange by start ASC to be sure. 2. cause I need to compare with a "parent" range, your FOR cycle fail check if for example last sub-range "end" end before the end of parent range... so I need also to check if parent["start"] == $timeRange[0]['start'] && parent['end'] == $timeRange[count($timeRange)-1]['end']